# Replaying Audio object in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to replay an audio sound each time the game starts (Using `Cocos2d` `javascript`). the first time it plays the sound but after that , each time i play it no sound appear.

here is my code

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('start');
        myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
             myAudio.currentTime = 0;
             myAudio.play();
            window.startGame = true;
        }, false);
        myAudio.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

See here:
http://forestmist.org/2010/04/html5-audio-loops/